# Как найти связь между таблицами Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Пытаюсь найти связь между таблицами и если если, то какая.

Условно у меня есть первая таблица, я хочу понять связана ли она как то с какой то другой таблицей:

Для этого попытался сделать так: зашел d PLSQL Debeloper`е в other_Users ---> далее нашел Юзера у кого есть эта таблица, открыл эту таблицу ---> в ней открыл вкладку "Constraints". Скриншот:
[image: Скриншот]
И далее не очень понимаю, если есть возможность подскажите пожалуйста.

Вот что, как мне показалось понял и что не понял:

1)В таблице есть главный и внешний ключ. Правда при самом запросе SELECT* from Table - название указанных ключей RTPL_PK и RTPL_RTPB_FK - не выгружается.
2)В Столбец R_TABLE_NAME - указано название таблицы на какую ссылается "данная" таблица то есть ссылается на таблицу ICE_TABLES. Такая таблица сущесвует.

В столбце R_CONSTRAINT_NAME указано наименование столбца PRTB_PK в таблице ICE_TABLES на которую ссылается "данная" таблица. Вот только проблема в том, что в таблице ICE_TABLES - нет столбца с названием PRTB_PK, а есть с названием PRTB_ID. И как это понимать, что то я не очень понимаю.

3)Не понял, что такое R_OWNER. Нагуглил, что это некая "схема", но что это значит не понятно. Единственно, что понятно, что название в столбце R_OWNER - "TC" - совпадает с названием Users в котором две эти таблицы находятся.

4)Так же меня смущают столбцы DELETE_RULE и STATUS - в которых напротив строки с "внешним ключом" стоит наименование NO_ACTION и DISABLED.
Это значит, внешний ключ не работает или что ?

5)И непонятно для чего столбца INDEX_ONWER и INDEX_NAME - что за информация в них указана и как ее нужно или можно использовать?

Comment: Внешний ключ фактически ссылается на первичный ключ другой таблицы, в R_CONSTRAINT_NAME содержится именно то, как называется колонка, имя констраинта первичного ключа другой таблицы не которую ссылка. "схема" - это имя пользователя владельца таблицы или другого объекта. И да, данный фореджен сейчас выключен и не работает. колонки index_ схема и название индекса, за счет которого обеспечивается ограничение

Comment: Mike, спасибо больше. Но позвольте еще все таки два вопроса:

1)Имя в R_CONSTRAINT_NAME - такого имени при запросе SELECT* MY_TABLE - не возвращает. Или когда создается внешний и главный ключ простым SELECT`ом не получить ?
2)И не понимаю, зачем тогда нужен этот внешний ключ, если он выключен ? Просто для информации, как связаны эти две таблицы ?

Comment: Конечно колонки с этим именем нет, это же имя первичного ключа той таблицы, а не колонки. Обратите внимание, первичный ключ может состоять и из нескольких колонок. надо уже лезть в описание ключей той таблицы на которую ссылка, искать ключ с этим именем и смотреть из чего он состоит. 2. А вот для чего выключен этот внешний ключ надо спросить у того, кто его выключал. Эта возможность вообще редко используется, ключи выключают в очень редких случаях при обслуживании таблиц, да того возможность и предусморена

Comment: Mike, но, если я создаю таблице с колонкой ID:                                                                                 
ID INT  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,                                                                         
PRIMARY KEY (ID)                                                                                                                                     То, если я запрошу данные таблицы SELECT* FROM My_Table, то эта колонка возвратится мне в качестве данных. При это этот столбец является Primary Key.

Comment: Да, но у любого объекта в БД, включая primary key всегда есть имя, даже если вы его явно не задавали. Для того, что бы этим объектом можно было управлять. Например что бы можно было удалить primary key, не удаляя при этом саму колонку. И имя это отлично от имени самой колонки, опять же что бы не перепутать при управлении.

Comment: Не путайте ограничение (constraint) типа primary key и колонку с данными, которая объявлена первичным ключом и на которой для обеспечения этого ограничения строится уникальный индекс